# How to scp files that match a particular date and name pattern

Tags: linux, scp

If I run an `ls -ltr` on `myserver.org:/some/path/dir`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 devops   devops   20727251 Mar 16 08:02 herp1.derp
-rw-r--r-- 1 devops   devops   24542012 Mar 16 08:03 herp2.derp
-rw-r--r-- 1 stduser devops    7716282 Mar 16 08:31 herp3.derp
-rw-r--r-- 1 stduser devops 1490729406 Apr 20 08:04 herp4.derp
-rw-r--r-- 1 stduser devops 1489656380 Apr 20 08:04 herp5.berp
-rw-r--r-- 1 stduser devops 1489960585 Apr 20 08:04 herp6.derp
-rw-r--r-- 1 stduser devops 1492748611 Apr 20 08:04 herp7.berp
```

I'm looking for a way to use `scp` in conjunction with a file pattern that will only return `*.berp` files that were last touched/modified on `Apr 20`. Usually my `scp` syntax is:

```
scp someUser@myserver.org:/some/path/dir/* .
```

But I want the file pattern `/some/path/dir/*` to only pull down `Apr 20 *.berp` files. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to fetch from a remote server via SSH, you could do it like this:

```
ssh someUser@myserver.org "cd /some/path/dir/; tar cz \`find . -name '*.berp' -daystart -mtime -5 -a -mtime +3\`" | tar xvz
```

You may have to play with the `mtime` values to get the exact date you want.